How to properly apply boundary conditions to Discontinuous Galerkin methods to equations with only source terms?
Okay say you have a system of equations of the type of:
$$ \partial_t u = f(v, \partial_x v, w, \partial_ w) \\
   \partial_t v = g(u,\partial_x u, w , \partial_x w) \\
   \partial_t w = h(u, \partial_x u, v, \partial_x v)$$
And I want to solve this system using Discontinuous Galerkin (DG) methods. How would I ever include Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions for any of these equations? Even if there is something in the source term to integrate by parts it will have no dependence on the variable that is being solved for. I’ve tried not setting any special boundary terms and this just leads to oscillations forming near the boundaries of my domain which is unsurprising. Any direction would be helpful. Totally willing to read and search more. I have been learning out of Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods by Hesthaven and Warburton. However, I haven’t found anything that comes close to addressing this situation.

If you can, re-write your PDE in the form
$$
\partial_t u + \partial_x \left(A_{00}(u, v, w) u + A_{01}(u, v, w) v + A_{02}(u, v, w) w \right) = S_0(u, v, w)\\
\partial_t v + \partial_x \left(A_{10}(u, v, w) u + A_{11}(u, v, w) v + A_{12}(u, v, w) w\right) = S_1(u, v, w)\\
\partial_t w + \partial_x \left(A_{20}(u, v, w) u + A_{21}(u, v, w) v + A_{22}(u, v, w) w\right) = S_2(u, v, w)
$$
where the RHS now has no spatial derivatives.
We can then define a vector of unknowns $q = [u, v, w]^T$, source $S = [S_0, S_1, S_2]^T$, and flux
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{00} & A_{01} & A_{02}\\
A_{10} & A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{20} & A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get
$$
\partial_t q + \partial_x \left(A q\right) = S
$$
This can then be solved using the methods described in Hesthaven and Warburton.
If you can't write the PDE in "conservation form" where the RHS is completely free of spatial derivatives, then you will have to rely on non-conservation form methods. For these you still want to separate out terms with spatial derivatives and those without, but the form you get will look like
$$
\partial_t q + \partial_x (A q) + H \partial_x q = S
$$
where $H$ is also a $3\times 3$ matrix and contains no spatial derivatives.
If your $H$ has spatial derivatives, then introduce auxiliary variables until you don't.
One method to solve these type of problems is that given by Rhebergen et al, JCP 2008.
The process for solving these is very similar to solving standard reaction-advection DG, you just have to define a continuous regularization $\phi_i$ across the discontinuity such that
$$
q_i = \begin{cases}
q_i|_L & \mathrm{if~} x \in ]a,x_d-\epsilon[\\
\phi_i\left(\frac{x-x_d+\epsilon}{2}\right) & \mathrm{if~} x \in ]x_d - \epsilon, x_d + \epsilon[\\
q_i|_R & \mathrm{if~} x \in ]x_d+\epsilon, b[
\end{cases}
$$
where $q_i|_L$ and $q_i|_R$ are the left and right states of the discontinuity and $\epsilon > 0$ is the region over where you are regularizing.
You can then find a non-conservative product flux (NCP flux) which is a modification of traditional numerical fluxes.
For further reference you can see Rhebergen's dissertation, where he has both space-time and method of lines DG methods for non-conservation form DG.

Thanks so much for both parts as the second half for non conservation form pde's is also something I was looking for. For the times when I can get it into conservation form, I see I can impose Dirichlet boundary conditions by up/down winding and then enforcing the boundary value on the appropriate value. Do I need to choose a different numerical flux for enforcing Neumann boundary conditions? I just don't see how to get a value for the derivative in my boundary integral in those cases. Thanks again for your time.

Neumann conditions may not be well defined in first order PDEs. At best usually you can specify the flux entering/leaving an interface.
